# Using proguard to generate apk with the common libaries

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I have the following library in my project

```
As jar:
httpcore-4.3.1.jar
httpmime-4.3.2.jar
libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar (latest GA version)

As import project
facebookSDK 3.6
```

I have added the following to `proguard-project.txt`

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
-keep class org.apache.**
-keep interface org.apache.**
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-dontwarn org.apache.**
```

and in the properties

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

It can generate the signed apk, but it will throw exception

```
NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams...
```

How to fix the problem? As I have add the keep class already? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

put `{ *; }` at the end of `-keep interface org.apache.**` and those -keep rules